# How can I get Vim to highlight syntax as well as textmate

Tags: python, vim, textmate

I like the idea of the of editing inside the terminal and like the key bindings of Vim, but the text highlighting in my Vim is much worse than in Textmate.  The comparison (textmate is first):

[image: Textmate]

[image: Vim]

Obviously Vim is much worse.  I've turned on syntax highlighting in my .vimrc, and have installed python.vim (not sure if this works with python 2.7).  Any suggesting on how to get it up to par would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You seem to mean that vim syntax highlighting is not as fine-grained as TextMates. You might want to use those words to get help instead of annoying those who use vim. Particularly as the answer suggest that it is not true.

Comment: I use vim too, it's not ment to annoy anyone.  And if they are, frankly, they're over-sensitive.

Comment: Well I for one tend to get annoyed when people claim some feature is worse than another without first finding out how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### EDIT 2:

If you edit `python.vim`, you'll find the following line:

```
syn keyword pythonStatement def class nextgroup=pythonFunction skipwhite
```

That's the crucial line for you. So basically, it styles `def` and `class` with `pythonStatement` and anything that follows it is styled with `pythonFunction`. You might want to rewrite it to something like

```
syn keyword pythonStatement def nextgroup=pythonFunction skipwhite
syn keyword pythonStatement class nextgroup=pythonClass skipwhite
```

where `pythonClass` is either defined by you as in my edit 1 (modify as you wish) or linked to one of the many color options offered by your scheme. Do `:hi` to see a list and link your new color style to an existing one as

```
HiLink pythonClass Special
```

(or something else). You might have to play around a little to hit your personal sweet spot.

I would've answered this the first time had you formulated your question better and made a direct request, instead of a rant. I did not quite understand what it is that you wanted. Anyway, I'll leave my earlier answer below.

---

#### Pre Edit 2:

Have you *tried to actually change the color theme* to something similar to what TextMate uses? Here's some example python code in my vim with beautiful syntax highlighting.

[image]

Of course, individual tastes differ and what I find appealing might not be appealing for others, but before brushing off vim and igniting a flame war here, you should take a look at what other color schemes are available. Google would be a good place to start.

#### EDIT:

Here's a quick example that shows you how to change the highlighting. This is an example with the current theme

[image]

The `blah` in class and `__blah__` are both styled by the highlighting scheme `pythonFunction`. So I just change it temporarily to a random color and underline it as

```
:hi pythonFunction cterm=underline ctermfg=217 ctermbg=16
```

The result is:

[image]

So this is just a general idea of how to do it. You should change these definitions in the color scheme file so that they'll be loaded each time. If you want `__blah__` to be different from the `blah` in class, you'll have to look at `python.vim` or whatever script you're using and tweak that accordingly.

Comment: @yoda I thought Yoda used Emacs?

Comment: I'm not trying to start a flame war.  Or brushing off vim, I prefer it like I said, but I just don't understand why I don't have the same verbose highlighting in both.

I've also tried many different themes, with each one lacking the highlighting I'd like.

Comment: @tshauck: Simply because you don't have the same color scheme in both vim and TextMate! Either try finding one that is similar to what you currently use in TextMate or pick one from the dozens available for vim (or even better: make one!). For starters, why don't you try either [jellybeans](https://github.com/nanotech/jellybeans.vim) or [wombat](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1778) just to cool your eyes ;)

Comment: @yoda, you misunderstand.  It's not about the colors themselves, it's about the fact that in textmate `Unit` and `__init__` are recognized as different and thus schemed differently.  I have jellybeans on my comp and the same things still happens.

Comment: @tschauck: Oh, that's just because the theme hasn't defined it that way. You can easily modify the theme if you don't mind getting your hands dirty :) If you type `:hi`, you'll see a list of highlighting schemes that vim knows about. In mine, for e.g., `pythonException xxx links to Exception` which in turn links to `Statement` which has the definition `term=bold ctermfg=103 guifg=#8197bf`. Now you can set `term=underline` to get an underline, or you can edit your `colorscheme.vim` and define colors you like for `pythonException`. Similarly for other key words.

Comment: What color scheme is that @yoda?

Comment: @Wahnfrieden: That's jellybeans. Please see my comment above (4th from the top) for a link to it.

Comment: @tschauck: You deleted your comment, but I answered it anyway. See my edit.